# Installing Python2.7 packages with Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

When I try to install wxPython3.0.2.0 with Homebrew 1.5.13 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2, it installs the package defaultly in Python3. How can I make Homebrew install it in Python2.7?

Comment: `brew install python@2`